# How to make white risotto

Tags: rice, italian-cuisine

I want to make white risotto, but I can't as the broth is usually brownish and makes the rice to have the same color. I don't know how to make/get white broth, any ideas how to make white risotto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally a white risotto would be made with chicken or fish stock. While the stock you get at the store is normally brown, [homemade stock](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/10/how-to-make-rich-flavorful-easy-chicken-stock.html) can be quite light in color if made properly and won't impart much color. Further, a splash of cream and a bit of a white cheese at the end of cooking can have a whitening effect.

Comment: And the OP mentioned in a comment on the other answer that it had a fish flavor so there you go!

Comment: Yeah, but the concept is still the same. If you look at a bunch of "white risotto" recipes, they all say you need to make your own _pale_ stock because store bought stock is too dark. Whether that's fish or chicken or even veg, the process and issue are the same. Make a pale colored stock.

Answer (score 1):

The liquid you use would very likely have to be clear or white (unless you could find some strange edible mix that turned clear or white).  That rules out most natural liquids other than water, milk, or pure vinegar (which would probably make the risotto more like sushi rice than risotto).  Sugar and salt of course could also be used to balance other flavors.  EDIT: coconut milk would also work--you'd get something like the base for Thai mango sticky rice (which is pretty tasty, but more desserty than risotto).

You might be able to get away with white wine, though that usually has some yellow color.  Some oils are also nearly clear and might impart good flavor.

Many artificial flavorings or extracts are also clear, but I can't imagine them making a good risotto--they just taste too artificial.

Are you trying to get it white just for fun?

EDIT: of course now that you mention it, fish and cheese are perfect for this.  I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of that.  You've got my vote @SourDoh. I've had risotto several times, but never the fish or cheese variety (mushroom is my favorite).  I've heard several Italian food experts say that fish and cheese should NEVER be used together, but separately would certainly be an option.  Carefully homemade chicken broth would work as well, but you may have to leave out the carrots to keep it clear and use the flesh of the onions and not whole onions with the skins as some TV chefs have recommended.

Comment: I saw it at a restaurant once and liked the presentation

Comment: What sort of flavor was it at the restaurant?

Comment: Fish flavor....

Comment: Interesting...you could purée any kind of white-fleshed fish, or possibly just poach the fish and use the poaching water (or milk).

Comment: Why not just normal fish stock?

Comment: "Normal" fish stock would be colored due to herbs and veggies.

Comment: @James but you suggested puréed fish or poaching water, not fish stock minus herbs and vegetables.

Comment: I think we're both on the same page here, using different terminology for the same thing.  The only difference I can see between poaching water and fish stock without herbs and vegetables is the relative proportion of bones to flesh, and the cooking time, neither of which is really well-defined anyway.  (Also, see my edits from 28Oct).

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Blanc makes a white risotto from "Tomato water"  Maybe there is a faster version of this somewhere...his takes 24 hours.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1l5iqiNfo4A

Comment: Welcome Evan, Link only answers are discouraged here, (content maybe taken down or be moved) can you edit your answer to include a brief description of the information included in the link.

Answer (score 0):

My mom would typically make risotto with shrimp stock.  She would often save the shells from other dishes, and make the stock from that and freeze it for another day, but if you're planning on making a shrimp risotto:

1. Get some shrimp with the shells still on. (preferably, heads still on, too).
2. De-vein the shrimp if it's not already (if you need to, peel it too)
3. Poach the shrimp 'til barely cooked through.
4. Peal the shrimp (if not already done) and take the heads off.  Reserve the meat.
5. Put the heads, shells, legs & tails back into the poaching liquid.
6. Continue simmering the liquid for about 20-30 minutes.  (maybe 10-15 if you have heads, but longer is better)

...

Make your risotto as normal (wine optional) using the poaching liquid as your broth.  Add the shrimp back in when the risotto's just about done.

If you start to run low on broth as you're making the risotto, just add some water back to the pot with the shells (and give it a chance to heat back up before adding it to the rice).   If you're getting close at the end, you can strain the broth to get the last bit of liquid without shells.

If you're going to make the stock to use another time, let it cook for a full hour before straining it.  We can get away with less time for the risotto as it's continuing to simmer as the rice is cooking.